# iOS Push Notification not received on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification

I am using pushy(Java API ) to send push notification to iOS devices. Till now I was using development provisioning profile and everything was working perfectly till I moved to distribution profile for OTA distribution. I am able to download the app into my devices successfully but not receiving any push notification.

- Device is getting register to push notification successfully.
- Checked pushy methods, its not throwing any error.
- Bundle ID in profile and app are matching (tried harcoding bundle id in info.plist)
- Checked certificate using openssl and its connecting to APNS server as well.
- Tried doing the process of creating profile and certificates all over again too.

Any help will be great. Thanks

Comment: once your app is being live with production profile you need to set sandbox mode False. this can be one reason check this in your backend side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with aps environment and issue got resolved by changing it to production